# Regular expression to extract special number

Tags: regex

How can i write a regular expression to extract the "integer+W" value

```
100W abc
60W cde
40W G9
60W CA2
```

The out put will be

100W
60W
40W
60W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[0-9]+W
```

That should do it. Here's a breakdown, in case you want it:

[0-9] (matches the range 0-9 [aka the digits])

+ (asks for 1 or more of the previous match [one or more digits, aka an integer])

W (self-explanatory)

Comment: It could be shortened to `\d+\w`.

Answer (score -1):

`/\b\d+\a+/` matches only numbers that have units e.g. `100mA`, and not words with digits inside of them e.g. `x4a`.

Comment: The OP just wants to match some digits followed by a literal `W`.

Comment: Ouch! I assumed 100W was 100 watts, and that he might need to match milliwatts or kilowatts at some point.